# reverse ordering using multibbl in moderncv

Tags: numbering, moderncv, multibib

I am required to format my CV in reverse chronological order and numbered down, starting with the total number of publications as the first number. I am using `moderncv` and the `multibbl` package since the CV needs separate sections with different numbering.
I have not been able to find a solution to this problem with the combination of `moderncv` and `multibbl`. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{multibbl}
\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
\newbibliography{papers}
\newbibliography{books}
\newbibliography{invited}
\newbibliography{presentations}

\begin{document}

\nocite{papers}{*}
\bibliographystyle{papers}{unsrt}
\bibliography{papers}{papers.bib}{Peer-reviewed Journal Articles}
\nocite{books}{*}
\bibliographystyle{books}{unsrt}
\bibliography{books}{books.bib}{Book Chapters}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `biblatex` and `etaremune` instead `multibib` to get what you want:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{citation01,
    Author = {Doe, John and Roe, Jane},
    Journal = {Fancy Journal},
    Pages = {123--145},
    Title = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit},
    Volume = {2},
    Year = {2012}}
  @article{citation02,
    Author = {Doe, John and Roe, Jane},
    Journal = {Fancy Journal},
    Pages = {12--34},
    Title = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {2014}}
  @book{citation03,
    Author = {Doe, John and Roe, Jane},
    Title = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.},
    publisher = {Company},
    location = {Somewhere},
    Year = {2013}}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,roman]{moderncv}
 
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  sorting=ydnt, maxbibnames=99, isbn=false, doi=false, firstinits, 
  terseinits, defernumbers, backend=biber
]{biblatex} % <=========================================================
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{etaremune} % <======================== for reverse numbering

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\renewcommand\labelenumi{[\theenumi]}
   \etaremune} % <======================================================
  {\endetaremune} % <===================================================
  {\item}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{CV}
\email{john@doe.com}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\nocite{citation01,citation02,citation03}

%\printbibheading[title={Publications}]
\printbibliography[type=article, title={Peer-reviewed Journal Articles},resetnumbers ]
\printbibliography[type=book, title={Book Chapters},resetnumbers ]

\end{document}
```

with the resulting pdf:

[image]